# How do I change only one part of the string with variable values

Tags: c, string, char

I have a question about how to change the "%d" of the text vector by the value of the variable a.

```
int a = 3;
char text[]= "How I change this value: %d"
```

And prints this:

> How I change this value: 3

Comment: `printf(text, a);` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you tried and how it failed. Please read [ask] page!! Also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I see no attempt and SO is not a code-writing service

Comment: https://ideone.com/fiRi38

Answer (score 1):

`snprintf` is what you are looking for, if you want to hold the result in a variable. `printf` will print to `stdout` (your terminal). 
You will find a great description [the man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

In your case, the following code will work:

```
int a = 3;
char text[]= "How I change this value: %d";
char buf[MAX_LEN];
snprintf(buf, MAX_LEN, text, a);
```

Now, the buffer `buf` will hold the string `"How I change this value: 3"`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to print it:​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
printf(text, a);
```